# Nginx how to block POST requests?

Tags: html, nginx, flask

Im trying to block POST request, sent from html:

```
    <form action = "http://localhost:80/post_it" method ="post">
         <p>Type something:</p>
         <p>
            <input type="text" name="n"/>
         </p>
         <p>
            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
         </p>
      </form>
```

in the nginx configuration, by this:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes 1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
location /post_it {
    limit_except GET {
        deny all;
    }
}
daemon off;
```

but it seems to have no effect, here are the logs:

```
[23/May/2021 16:36:39] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[23/May/2021 16:36:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[23/May/2021 16:36:49] "POST /post_it HTTP/1.1" 302 -
[23/May/2021 16:36:49] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

submitted data also goes through flask function which redirects user back to main page, but I assume the POST request should still be denied. Nginx and flask app are run from one docker container. What am I missing here?

Comment: `/post_to_psql_db` doesn't match `/post_it`

Comment: @Quentin mistake when rewriting to stack, it does match in my code

Comment: Since your question is tagged Flask you could simply specify that the route should only allow GET requests, which should be the case by default.